# How can I add a field to a document in Firestore and then add a collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do the following:

[image]

I am using the following call:

```
 db.collection("TagEvents").doc(rfid).add({ currentStatus: riderOnBus }, { merge: true }).collection(eventDate).add(jsonDeviceMessage)
                    .then(function (data) {
                        console.log('Firebase data: ', data);
                        context.succeed();                 
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log('Firebase error: ', error);
                        context.fail();
                    });
```

It won't let me add a collection after I add a field to the doc!!

What am I doing wrong???

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It won't let me add a collection after I add a field to the doc!!

There is no way you can add a document and a subcollection in a single go. To solve this, you should do two separate operations. The first one would be to add the document to your `TagEvents` collection:

```
db.collection("TagEvents").doc(rfid).add({ currentStatus: riderOnBus }, { merge: true }).then(/* ... */);
```

And the second one would be to create a new reference and add `jsonDeviceMessage` to your `eventDate` subcollection.

```
db.collection("TagEvents").doc(rfid).collection(eventDate)
    .add(jsonDeviceMessage).then(/* ... */);
```